# Login is not displayed after authorization

Tags: java, angular, spring

I want then user logined(authorize) in header menu displayed menu with username(login) like at picture.

[image]

For this purpose i have the corresponding code in angular:

File header.component.html:

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <a routerLink="" id="nav_logo">
    DishOnline
  </a>
  <div id="nav_right_section">
    <a routerLink="/loginPage">
      Вход
    </a>

    <button [hidden]=" receivedAnswer!==undefined && receivedAnswer!==null" mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">{{receivedAnswer.login}}</button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item>Мой кабинет</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Выйти</button>
    </mat-menu>

  </div>
</nav>
```

File header.component.ts:

```
import {Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { LoginNameService} from '../services/loginName.service';
import {LoginName} from '../classes/loginName';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls : ['./header.component.scss'],

  providers: [LoginNameService]
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit
{
  receivedAnswer: LoginName;

  loginNameObject: LoginName=new LoginName();


  constructor(private loginNameService: LoginNameService) {}
  submit() {
    this.loginNameService.postData()
      .subscribe((data: LoginName) => {},

        error => console.log(error)
      );
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.receivedAnswer=this.loginNameObject;
    this.submit();
  }

}
```

I send on server(backend - Spring Boot) empty POST request, using for this service loginName.service.ts.

File loginName.service.t:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable()
export class LoginNameService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  postData() {

    // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
    let baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8089';

    return this.http.post(baseUrl + '/loginName', null);
  }
}
```

From service i have the answer in JSON:

```
{"login":"DishOnline"}
```

But received login not displayed in header.

Code receiving login on backend(Spring Boot):

```
package com.greatproject.dishonline.controller;

import com.greatproject.dishonline.service.MyUserDetailsService;
import com.greatproject.dishonline.service.MyUserPrincipal;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@RestController
public class AuthorizationController {

    @RequestMapping("/loginName")
    public  @ResponseBody
    Map<String,String>  loginName(Model model,
                                  Authentication authentication,
                                  HttpSession session,
                                  MyUserPrincipal principal

    ) {
        String login = "";

        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        login = auth.getName(); //get logged in username

        Map<String, String> mapLoginName = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mapLoginName.put("login", login);

        return  mapLoginName;
    }

}
```

Please help me resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the username off the principal.  Try adding the principal.username to the model and retrieving it on the ui that way.

Comment: Welcome @Paul Pearson on StackOverflow, It would be helpful if you attached some reference with your answer.

Comment: Paul, do you mean model spring or angular ?

Comment: Spring.  In your controller add the principal.username to the model.  And then obviously you can use that in Angular.